# How to test a lazy loaded components within the react router?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, jestjs, react-testing-library, webpack-module-federation

I need a way to test a component in which two other components are lazy loaded.

We are using **webpack module federation**. So here `ComponentOne` and `ComponentTwo` are micro-frontends that are lazy loaded inside the `App` component. So the `App` component here is the container application that contains both apps and provides routing between them.

**My `App.tsx` looks like this:**

```
import { Suspense, lazy } from 'react';
import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';

const ComponentOne = lazy(() => import('components/ComponentOne));
const ComponentTwo = lazy(() => import('components/ComponeentTwo'));

export const App = () => {
  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<div>FallbackDummy</div>}>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<ComponentOne />} />
        <Route path="/two" element={<ComponentTwo />} />
      </Routes>
    </Suspense>
  );
};
```

**This App component is used within my `bootstrap.tsx` file like this:**

```
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

import { App } from './app/app';

render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root'),
);
```

**My `App.test.tsx` looks like this:**

```
import { Suspense } from 'react';
import {
  render,
  RenderResult,
} from '@testing-library/react';
import { App } from './App';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';

describe('App component', () => {
  let testedComponent: RenderResult;

  beforeEach(() => {
    testedComponent= render(
      <Suspense fallback={<div>FallbackDummy</div>}>
        <App />
      </Suspense>
    );
  });

  test('should match snapshot', () => {
    expect(testedComponent).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

The test runs without the `<Routes>` and `<Route>` components (so only wrapped in ). But I can't manage to use the router in my tests.

Answer (score 2):

I found this question while trying to test a regular lazy-loaded component, and I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66690463) here that worked for me. Basically, you need to use the [`waitFor`](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async/#waitfor) function in `react-testing-library` so that everything loads up before completing your `expect` call.

Here are the relevant snippets from the answer linked above:

`LazyLoad.jsx`:

```
import React, {lazy} from 'react'
const LazyComponent = lazy(() => import('./LazyComponent'))
const LazyLoad = () => {
   return (
      <div>
         <div> Lazy component is here: </div>
         <React.Suspense fallback={null}>
             <LazyComponent />
         </React.Suspense>
      </div>
   )
}
export default LazyLoad
```

`LazyComponent.jsx`:

```
import React from 'react'
export default () => <div>I am lazy ! </div>
```

`LazyLoad.spec.jsx`:

```
import React from 'react'
import {render, waitFor } from 'react-testing-library'
import LazyLoad from 'LazyLoad'

test('renders lazy component', async () => {
    const { getByText } = render(<LazyLoad />)
    await waitFor(() => expect(getByText('I am lazy !' )).toBeInTheDocument())
})
```